# SQL - select first of every duplicate column but keep records with null value in column

Tags: sql

suppose this is the table and content:

```
name      phone
Adam      123
Tony      234
John
Pawl      
Spenser   123
Bill      345
```

expected result is:

```
name      phone
Adam      123
Tony      234
John
Pawl      
Bill      345
```

Spenser - removed (duplicate phone)
John & Pawl - not removed (null not considered duplicates)

Comment: Please tag your DBMS product?

Comment: How to know which "duplicates" to keep or remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a version of SQL that doesn't support CTEs, you can generate the desired result using a `UNION` query. The first part of the `UNION` gets a unique (`MIN`) value for `name` for each `phone` which is not `NULL`; the second returns all `name` values where `phone` is `NULL`:

```
SELECT MIN(name) AS name, phone
FROM phones
WHERE phone IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY phone
UNION
SELECT name, phone
FROM phones
WHERE phone IS NULL
```

Output

```
name    phone
Adam    123
Tony    234
Bill    345
John    null
Pawl    null
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7n92nNtvSWGpQxU5VhHncC/1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to retain the alphabetically "earliest" name, in the case two or more names happen to have the same phone number, we can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELCET name, phone, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY phone ORDER BY name) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT name, phone
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1 OR phone IS NULL;
```

The null check on the `phone` field in the above `WHERE` clause spares all records which are missing phone numbers from having to be the earliest.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use This  Query

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT name, phone, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY phone ORDER BY name) rn
    FROM testtable
)

SELECT 
    name, 
    IIF(rn=1,phone,NULL)

FROM cte
```

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL (there is no `IIF` in SQL). Please mention the DBMS product for which this works.

Comment: in SQL 2019 And you can replace that with  CASE   "CASE WHEN rn=1 Then phone ELSE NULL"

Comment: There is no such thing as "SQL 2019" (because "SQL" is a standard for a query language not the name of a specific database product and there has been no version named 2019 of the SQL standard). Do you mean SQL Server 2019? The `CASE` expression has been available in the SQL standard and SQL Server for decades.

Comment: YES Mean SQL server 2019 and You can use Case in SQL Language